# How to activate onChange with React-Select when value is based on a state

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, dropdown, react-select

I have a Select Dropdown which value is connected to another Select Dropdown. When I select from the first, I change the state of a Hook. The new value does display on the second Select Dropdown but it does not activates the onChange event handler, so I can't grab the data.

Here's the code for the second select Dropdown:

```
<Select 
  name="second-dropdown"
  value={{label: secondState}}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Any ideas? Been trying setting the onChange like this:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
```

But nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the second Select is always **secondState** and what you should do in onChange function is like this

```
handleChange = (value) = {
this.setState({secondState:value});
}
```